# How to change the icon of the Auth0 LockActivity for android?

Tags: android, google-oauth, auth0

I'm using [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) to manage the security of an android app and I need to customize my login activity.

I use the default LockActivity of the [Lock.Android](https://github.com/auth0/Lock.Android) library. How I can change the icon of the LockActivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the LockActivity by implementing a style that inherits from `Lock.Theme` and overrides the `Auth0.Title.Icon` style attribute with your own app logo.

Here is an code example:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Lock.Theme" parent="Lock.Theme">
      <item name="Auth0.Title.Icon">@style/eXigo.Lock.Theme.Title.Icon</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.Lock.Theme.Title.Icon" parent="Lock.Theme.Title.Icon">
       <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_login_main</item>
</style>
```

Then in your Android Manifest file you need to change style of the LockActivity with your customized style.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.auth0.lock.LockActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Lock.Theme" >
```

You can see the other fields you can customize [here](https://github.com/auth0/Lock.Android/blob/master/lock/src/main/res/values/styles.xml).